415 Unsupported Media Type при отправке данных FormData через POST (но в postman работает)
На 3-ем скрине метод отправки запроса. apiInstance - экземпляр axios с параметром baseUrl и withCreditails, больше конфигураций нет.
При отправке получаю 415 и сообщение и том, что не поддерживается application/octet-stream media type, хотя в запросе указал Content-Type multipart/form-data, что видно на первом скрине.
На первом скрине raw запрос с браузера, на втором с postman. В postman запрос уходит нормально.
Если сравнить их содержимое, можно увидеть что у запроса в postman есть информация о body (выделено на 2-ом скрине), т.е. два файла и поле с json str. В браузерном запросе этого нет.
Никогда не обращал внимания как браузер формирует запрос с form data и пошёл по другим своим проектам где так же присутствует загрузка файла, рабочая. Такая же ситуация - браузер не добавляет эту информацию как в postman, но запросы там рабочие, ничего предъявить разработчику апи не могу.
1. Вопрос в том, на чьей стороне проблема. Вводит в заблуждение то, что в postman всё работает хорошо, бэк корректно принимает запрос оттуда.
2. И причём тут ortet-stream media type вообще, если в запросе чётко видно что уходит multipart/form-data.
На бэке используется java и spring, всё что знаю.
Благодарю за любую помощь.
P.S.
Обёртка Blob над licenseRequest ничего не изменит, если вдруг будут такие предположения.





Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

У вас JSON.stringify применяется к значению, которое уже хранит результат JSON.stringify.

Точно, по невнимательности. Сейчас всё работает, спасибо
